# Difference between .NET Framework versus .NET Standard?

Tags: .net

My apologies if this question is a bit naive but how can you tell if a project is in .NET Framework versus .NET Standard. I have a project that was originally written in .NET Framework 4.+ and have been asked to confirm that it has been updated to .NET Standard. How would I be able to determine this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NETPlatform vs .NETStandard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40442460/netplatform-vs-netstandard)

Comment: You should start from posts https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/september/net-standard-demystifying-net-core-and-net-standard to fully understand what is .NET Standard. A .NET Framework based project can be converted to .NET Standard based, but very likely you need to create a .NET Standard class library and cut/paste code over to see what breaks. Portability Analyzer only helps partially.

Answer (score 0):

.Net Framework is the original version of .Net that is dependent on the Windows operating system. .Net Standard is a compatability API that was created to allow assemblies (the .net term for .dll files), to be compiled for either .Net Framework or .Net Core (.Net Core is the new version of .Net that can be run on either windows or Linux).

.Net Standard provides a slightly smaller API that doesn't have some of the platform specific features in it. The current version of .Net Standard is 2.1.

You can test an assembly to see if it can be switched to .Net Standard using the [.Net portability analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/portability-analyzer).